# Eclipselink - ID after persisting is still null

Tags: orm, jpa, entity, nullpointerexception, eclipselink

I've got a problem to persist an Entity and to get the id after the persist happened.
I can see that the data was created in the database, with the right id, but the id is still null at the object.

Heres my entity:

```
@Entity
public class Bookmark {

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String name;

@Column(nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date createdAt;

@ManyToOne
private Page page;

@ManyToOne
private Color color;

@ManyToOne
private User user;

...
..
```

And here is my Code where I Create the Entity:

```
//init bookmark from json basic data
 Bookmark bookmark = new Bookmark(currentUser,page);

 bookmark.setName(name);
 bookmark.setColor(color);

 //set User relationship for the bookmark
 currentUser.getBookmarks().add(bookmark);

 //save the altered entities
 tx.begin();
 em.merge(currentUser);
 em.persist(bookmark);
 tx.commit();


 //Build the response
 System.out.println("uriInfo:"+uriInfo+ "bookmark:"+bookmark);
 URI bookmarkUri = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path(bookmark.getId().toString()).build();
```

I'm getting a nullpointer Exception at the last line because getId() results in null.
How can i avoid that?

Comment: I set the debug level a little bit higher an see something like that: RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.1.v20100817-r8050): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
Error Code: 0
Call: INSERT INTO BOOKMARK (CREATEDAT, NAME, COLOR_ID, USER_ID, PAGE_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
 bind => [2010-11-27, TestBookmark, 1, 1, 3]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(Bookmark with id null for page 22 of the book 'BlaBook' with the id 1)

Comment: Seems that it depends on Tomcat, because my JUnit tests are fine. What could be wrong with the code in context of a Tomcat Servlet?

Comment: Another strange fact: output of  System.out.println("Contains: "+ em.contains(bookmark)); is "Contains: false", so it seems that the object is not managed by the entity manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem. The root of the problem is the order of the commands to persist the bookmark.
This is the right order:

```
em.persist(bookmark);
em.merge(currentUser);
```

So first of all you have to persist the entity and after that you can merge the entity of the relationships of that entity.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the Identity PK generation strategy, perhaps you should add `@ReturnInsert` to your `@Id` column, to force the PK to be returned on insert statements.